# Regex match pattern unless it's part of a bigger pattern

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I need to title-case any words that appear in all caps as part of a string, unless there are more than three of them consecutively.

For example:

```
really FOO BAR foo bar
```

should become

```
really Foo Bar foo bar
```

but

```
REALLY FOO BAR FOO BAR
```

should stay as-is.

Another example, Raw string:

```
You say goodbye but i say HELLO HELLO hello i don't know WHY YOU SAY GOODBYE I SAY HELLO.
```

Desired output:

```
You say goodbye but i say Hello Hello hello i don't know WHY YOU SAY GOODBYE I SAY HELLO.
```

I tried something like the below, but that's titlecasing the string with the first three spaces regardless of context.

```
re.sub("([A-Z]+\s? [A-Z]+\s? [A-Z]+\s?)", lambda pat: pat.group(1).title(), s)
```

Comment: Try [this solution](https://ideone.com/2NwhKJ), see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Wsds0F/1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may match sequences of 3 or more whitespace-separated uppercase words and "skip" them while matching and capturing (for further processing) all other uppercase words.

Use the following regex

```
\b[A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+){2,}|\b([A-Z]{2,})\b
```

See [its demo online](https://regex101.com/r/Wsds0F/1/). Note that in case you want to avoid matching single-char words (like `I`) replace `+` with `{2,}` (to match 2 or more letters).

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `[A-Z]+` - 1+ ASCII uppercase letters
- `(?:\s+[A-Z]+){2,}` - 2 or more occurrences of 1+ whitespace chars followed with 1+ ASCII uppercase letters (replace `+` with `{2,}` to match 2 or more letters)
- `|` - or
- `\b([A-Z]{2,})\b` - a whole word consisting of 2 or more ASCII uppercase letters.

[In Python](https://ideone.com/2NwhKJ), the code will look like

```
import re
s='really FOO BAR foo bar and REALLY FOO BAR FOO BAR'
rx = r'\b[A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+){2,}|\b([A-Z]{2,})\b'
res = re.sub(rx, lambda pat: pat.group(1).title() if pat.group(1) else pat.group(), s)
print(res) # => really Foo Bar foo bar and REALLY FOO BAR FOO BAR
```

The `pat.group(1).title() if pat.group(1) else pat.group()` means that Group 1 value is titlecased only if it was matched, else the whole match is pasted back unprocessed.